# Is PostgreSQL V10 and above is compatible with wso2 version 6.4.0?

Tags: wso2, compatibility, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We need to know whether upgrading Postgres to higher version than 9.2.24 will it be compatible or not with the WSO2 v6.4.0. Need this information in exercise while fixing the vulnerability detected on Postgres server "PostgreSQL PassTheHash Protocol Design Weakness Detected"

Comment: If you upgrade, then upgrade straight to 14. Postgres 10 will be unsupported (and thus won't receive  any security fixes) in about 6 months.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name,
Thanks for your suggestion. But as per compatibility only upgradation will be performed, i am not sure v14 is compatible with WSO2 EI 6.4.0 or not. i'll explore on the same . kindly have a look into  this. https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+DBMSs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+DBMSs. It seems higher versions are already compatible.